# Stability issues after updating from 17.10 to 18.04 (no drivers, browser crash)

Tags: drivers, updates, 18.04

I have a Thinkpad T430 with Intel Core i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz (and embedded graphics unit). So, I have updated from 17.10 to 18.04 (what a joke).

First and most important:

- There are no additional drivers to select, even though they always were there. Yes, I have enabled `Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)`, run `sudo apt update`.

Then goes the:

- Chromium tabs with video media (youtube, webm, flash etc) simply crash. Firefox and media players are okay.
- Visual artifacts in Atom editor ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6OjN.png)). Sublime Text is okay.

Also update killed systemd service for MariaDB to start at boot. Maybe some other things too, I have yet to look at all of that. System in general feels slower and even the response from input in terminal emulator is slower.

#### NOW: 
 **How do I get proprietary drivers?**

And then maybe fix the visual artifacts.

Comment: American girls are fat ugly bitches.